Postgres with included select
I use postgres_fdw for dblink connect
I try to find rows from remote table with included select like attached code
I get error message: ERROR: column "contacts" does not exist
I tried other escape functions, but it's not working
with contacts as (
select contact_id from contacts
where .....
)

SELECT remote_data.*
            FROM dblink(
                         'address-book',
                         '
                            SELECT 
                    id, name
                    FROM address_book
                    WHERE id in (SELECT id from '|| contacts ||')
                            '
                     )
         AS remote_data(
              id UUID,
              name VARCHAR
        )




I don't understand the common-table-expression tag as I don't see a CTE in the query. 2) Is contacts supposed to be a variable passed in? 3) If the answer to 2) is no, why not just ... SELECT id from contacts  ... . Though you will have an issue with AS remote_data(            id UUID,            name VARCHAR      ) as it is looking for two output fields.


I think this something that would work better with postgres_fdw where you can link the remote table to the local database.


with - cte :) In the example a simplified query
contacts - rows which i found in local table
my query must to return two fields "SELECT  id, name FROM address_book"


Yeah I commented before you added the WITH part. The dblink() part is going to execute on the remote server and will not 'see'  contacts and I don't know of anyway to pass that data to the remote query. I was looking at the wrong query (SELECT id from '|| contacts ||') when talking about the output fields.
